# JSF 2.2 + PrimeFaces 3.5 + PrettyFaces-Jsf 3.3.3

Tags: jsf, primefaces, prettyfaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use PrettyFaces in my web app because SEO it's not friendly with it!
I configured PrettyFaces without problems and it works fine!
But.....I can see a strange "url behavior".

This is my pretty-config:

```
<url-mapping id="homepage"> 
    <pattern value="/homepage" /> 
    <view-id value="/pages/homepage/homepage.jsf" /> 
</url-mapping> 

<url-mapping id="registrazioneUtente">
    <pattern value="/registrazioneUtente" />
    <view-id value="/pages/homepage/registrazioneUtente.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

this is my homepage link:

```
<h:link outcome="pretty:homepage" >
    <p:graphicImage url="/resources/images/logo.jpg" height="200px" title="www.eventicinofili.com" /> 
</h:link>
```

and this is my registrazioneUtente link:

```
<h:link outcome="pretty:registrazioneUtente" value="#{ApplResLbl.registrazioneLink}" styleClass="gialloFont" title="#{ApplResLbl.registrazioneAlt}" />
```

When I access my web app I can see this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/EventiCinofiliWEB/homepage
```

When I click registrazioneUtente link I can see this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/EventiCinofiliWEB/registrazioneUtente?jffi=%2Fpages%2Fhomepage%2FregistrazioneUtente.jsf%3Fcom.ocpsoft.mappingId%3DregistrazioneUtente&jftfdi=
```

and when I come back to the homepage with homepage link I can see this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/EventiCinofiliWEB/homepage?jffi=%2Fpages%2Fhomepage%2Fhomepage.jsf%3Fcom.ocpsoft.mappingId%3Dhomepage&jftfdi=
```

I'm going crazy because I can not remove jffi and jftfdi id from the URL!

I hope in your help!
Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Vale

Comment: SOLVED!

Instead to use 

    <h:link outcome="pretty:homepage" >
        <p:graphicImage url="/resources/images/logo.jpg" height="200px" title="www.eventicinofili.com" /> 
    </h:link>

now, I'm using

    <pretty:link mappingId="homepage">
        <p:graphicImage url="/resources/images/logo.jpg" height="200px" title="www.eventicinofili.com" />
    </pretty:link>

and it's working fine!

Comment: Nice to hear you solved your issue. I already answered you post on the forums. So if you don't want to replace all your links with <pretty:link> you could have a look at the post and perhaps provide a minimal sample app to reproduce this issue: http://ocpsoft.org/support/topic/startup-with-prettyfaces/#post-24973

Comment: You should use PrimeFaces 4.0 with JSF 2.2. The 3.5 version targets JSF 2.0-2.1 and is incompatible with 2.2.